# Mongodb - Find Embedded Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I have a collection called Forms:  Inside that collection i have a sub collect called Form_Fields.  So a document may look like this:

```
}
   "_id": ObjectId("4f2984b1af06e80418000000"),
   "Form_Name": "Users",
   "Form_Fields": [
                  {"Field_Name": "First_Name"},
                  {"Field_Name": "Last_Name"}
                  ]
}
```

So how do i find the array for the form fields?

I have tried :

```
$collection->find(array("Form_Name"=>"Users");
```

but that does return the array

```
First_Name, Last_Name
```

What i am trying to accomplish is to perform a find that will locate the document with the Form_Name = Users and then return an array that contains all of the Form_Fields.

I know this isn't right but something like:

```
find(array("Form_Name=>"Users"(array(Form_Fields)))
```

and it return the array of only the 2 Field_Names?

Can someone help me to construct the "find" to find the 'Users" form elements in an array. so i want to find all the 'Form_Fields' inside the document with the 'Form_Name' = 'Users' document.

Thank you.

**Update**

I want to search an embedded doc with a particular parent document attribute. So lets say i have a collection "Forms" and embedded inside that collection i have a doc called "Form_Fields". So that each form has embedded/related fields. I wanted to find all embedded form fields for the doc with the attribute "Form_Name":"Users".

Should i perform an embedded search like:

$cursor = $collection->find(array("Form_Name"=>"Users"));

//this brings back the doc where form_name = users.
//Should i then expand that search by using something like:

$cursor -> find("the search to find all embedded Form_Fields")

??

Answer (score 1):

You can specify what field from a document you want to fetch. Here's your example in javascript.

```
db.collection.find({"Form_Name": "Users"}, {"Form_Fields": 1});
```

This will return a document (or several) with two fields, `_id` and `Form_Fields`. If you don't want the `_id`, you have to specifically exclude it.

```
db.collection.find({"Form_Name": "Users"}, {"Form_Fields": 1, "_id": -1});
```

Comment: but what if i want to fetch them all? Also i am using php not shell, can you give example in php?  thank you.

Comment: Fetch all what? Also, you should be able to translate from shell language to PHP yourself, since all examples in the doc are in javascript.

Comment: Yes i can translate.  Ok so let me restate the q for clarity.  I want to search an embedded doc with a particular parent attribute.  So lets say i have a collection "Forms" and embedded inside that collection i have a doc called "Form_Fields".  So that each form has embedded/related fields.  I wanted to find all embedded form fields for the doc with the attribute "Form_Name":"Users".  See my update above.

Comment: @user982853, that's basically what this code does. Only it doesn't give you a naked array, but rather a partial document with only that field, `Form_Fields`.

Comment: But i am trying to return all the fields!

Comment: @user982853: so, you just want to load a document with `"Form_Name": "Users"`? Then remove second parameter from my code.